# eval function - order of evaluation

Tags: javascript, html

When i give the below statement the output is displayed as -200.

can anyone help me to figure what actually happens inside eval()

```js
alert(eval(5-5*5+"5 + 5"));
```

Comment: It isn't complicated. Just step through each part of the statement in turn paying attention to operator precedence.  (And run it without the eval for a clue)

Comment: Have you tried running `5-5*5+"5 + 5"` to see what string it creates?

Comment: it creates -205+5 and how it generates -205? @apsillers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two steps : a string is computed by the operation you see, and then that string is evaled.

What you're evaling is the result of

```
5-5*5+"5 + 5"
```

which is

```
( 5 - (5*5) ) + "5 + 5"
```

which is

```
-20 + "5 + 5"
```

Here's a slightly tricky part : [adding a number and a string is done via string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_(.2B)) so the result of that operation is

```
"-20" + "5 + 5"
```

which gives

```
"-205 + 5"
```

**Then** that string is evaled, which gives `-200`

Comment: why it is printing -205. how the evaluation occurs?